# now() - current time issue for mule app deployed on Any point platform

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

I have a question about the current time issue in our Mule App, which is deployed on any point platform.
When using 'now()' in mule app, it consistently returns a time that is one hour different as Europe/Berlin time as I expected.
Therefore, I made a change to explicitly request the time in the Europe/Berlin timezone. See below

```
var formattedCurrentTime= now() as String { format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", timezone: "Europe/Berlin" }
```

But it  still return same result , Do you have any idea about it?
PS: The problem is only on deployed Mule App at anypoint platform.
With local system or on    https://dataweave.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave
It works correctly

Any hints or ideas? thank you all (dear mule riders) in advance!

Comment: Daylight savings time perhaps ?  Perhaps have a table of known values for this, have the code look at it, and add or subtract the difference if that country is still using daylight savings time?

Comment: Here is a link to Europe timezones, I see that Germany is a +1  so I think it has daylight savings in effect, so perhaps this link is confirmation of my theory:
--> https://www.timeanddate.com/time/europe/

Comment: Still no comment after edits?  Are you looking for prefab code to do this, or are you holding out hoping this isn't the correct reason?

Comment: Note .. I did research on this .. how old is your code?  CloudHub 1.0 fixed the issue in June 2023 .. so if you haven't patched .. maybe this will fix it.   In CloudHub 2.0 its suppose to be auto fixed, but it sounds like you are using AnyPoint the info seems to indicate a manual JDK upgrade might be required, so good luck with that, if that is the case.

Comment: What version of Mule are you using including patch level? Are you deploying in CloudHub? Is the time difference positive or negative? Share the actual and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Mule applications deployed on CloudHub always use UTC as the timezone. Berlin timezone is UTC+1, which probably explains the difference. What you should do is to change the timezone of the date time returned by `now()` before formatting it to a string.

Example

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    now: now() as String { format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" },
    nowToBerlin: (now() >> "Europe/Berlin") as String { format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "now": "2023-12-26T19:18:51",
  "nowToBerlin": "2023-12-26T20:18:51"
}
```

For more information read: https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dataweave-cookbook-change-time-zone